# Liquid If Value Blank Set to Default Value

Tags: liquid

In liquid, is there anything similar to js `const val = product.abc || ""`

Would like to find similar in liquid `{%- assign val = product.abc | "" -%}`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I usually assign a default value, then overwrite it based on some condition:

```
{%- assign val = "" -%}
{%- if product.abc != "" -%}
    {%- assign val = product.abc -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

Liquid doesn't have that fancy OR functionality when declaring variables, however the *default* filter might be close:

```
{%- assign product_price = "" -%}
{{ product_price | default: 2.99 }}
```